# Best practice to handle vhosts in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, virtualhost

What is the best practice to handle virtual hosts in node.js?

I need to route domains to each individual http server..

```
http://api.localhost:8080 => localhost:9000
http://www.localhost:8080 => localhost:9001
https://secure.localhost:8080 => localhost:9002 // this request is HTTPS
```

I am using express http

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503841/virtual-hosting-with-standalone-node-js-server) might have the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Can't get `http-proxy` to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360318/node-http-proxy-route-domains-to-individual-http

Comment: I use node-http-proxy and have some useful links in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652863/nodejs-managed-hostings-vs-vps/12652947#12652947

Answer (score 1):

It's very common to use nginx on port 80, and then define servers (vhosts) within nginx with a reverse proxy to your node servers. The reason it's so common is because nginx is exceptional at serving static content, so you let it do just that by telling it your public directory location.

Here's an example of a server (vhost) config. You would create one `server { }` block, and change the server_name for each vhost:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
  }
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|png|gif|woff|ico|map|js|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|flv|swf|html|htm)$ {
    root /home/empurium/code/davinci/public;
  }
}
```