# VirtualHost name based routing in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx

How could i do a vitualhost names based routing for running multiple sites on a single server.

I thought of installing nginx and proxying the request to nodejs, and doing name based routing for different domains in nginx.

Does it make sense to put nginx infront of nodejs ?

will it affect the performance of nodejs, since i have high performance requirements which currently being satisfied by nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Putting nginx in front of node.js is actually common practice. Here's some more information:

[Best practice to handle vhosts in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364524/best-practice-to-handle-vhosts-in-nodejs/22365876#22365876)